# LaTeX VScode on mac - stuck on activating extensions

Tags: pdf, compiling, vscode

I've reinstalled VScode and all the libraries several times but I still can't get my latex project to compile. VScode is stuck on *activating extensions*:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you installed a TeX distribution?

Comment: Of course, I'm using MacTex

Comment: We get a lot of questions from new users who have installed an editor but not a distribution; hence I needed to check. Can you compile your document from the command line?

Comment: Yes, MacTex works fine. It's an issue localised to the VSCode editor.

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/76459905/2777074

Comment: Same problem on windows 11